# Take 2 steps at a time in a 2d matrix

Tags: java, matrix, breadth-first-search

You are given a MxN 2D grid initialized with these three possible values.

-1 - A wall or an obstacle.

0 - A gate.

INF - Infinity means an empty room

Fill each empty room with the distance to its nearest gate.

For example, given the 2D grid:

```
INF  -1  0  INF
INF INF INF  -1
INF  -1 INF  -1
0    -1 INF INF
```

After running the function, the 2D grid should be:

```
3  -1   0   1
2   2   1  -1
1  -1   2  -1
0  -1   3   4
```

I used BFS starting from every 0 (gate), and keep updating the minimum value of every INF. Below is my code, it works.

```
public void wallsAndGates(int[][] rooms) {
    if(rooms==null || rooms.length==0) return;
    int row=rooms.length;
    int col=rooms[0].length;
    Queue<Integer> q=new LinkedList<Integer>();
    for(int i=0; i<row; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<col; j++){
            if(rooms[i][j]==0) {
                boolean[][] visited=new boolean[row][col];
                q.add(i*col+j);
                bfs(rooms,q,visited);
            }
        }
    }
}  

public void bfs(int[][] rooms, Queue<Integer> q, boolean[][] visited){
    int row=rooms.length;
    int col=rooms[0].length;
    int distance=1;
    while(!q.isEmpty()){
        int size=q.size();
        for(int m=0; m<size; m++){
            int num=q.poll();
            int i=num/col;
            int j=num%col;
            if(j-1>=0 && rooms[i][j-1]!=0 && rooms[i][j-1]!=-1 && !visited[i][j-1]){
                rooms[i][j-1]=Math.min(rooms[i][j-1],distance);
                q.add(i*col+j-1);
                visited[i][j-1]=true;
            }
            if(j+1<rooms[0].length && rooms[i][j+1]!=0 && rooms[i][j+1]!=-1 && !visited[i][j+1]){
                rooms[i][j+1]=Math.min(rooms[i][j+1],distance);
                q.add(i*col+j+1);
                visited[i][j+1]=true;
            }
            if(i-1>=0 && rooms[i-1][j]!=0 && rooms[i-1][j]!=-1 && !visited[i-1][j]){
                rooms[i-1][j]=Math.min(rooms[i-1][j],distance);
                q.add((i-1)*col+j);
                visited[i-1][j]=true;
            }
            if(i+1<rooms.length && rooms[i+1][j]!=0 && rooms[i+1][j]!=-1 && !visited[i+1][j]){
                rooms[i+1][j]=Math.min(rooms[i+1][j],distance);
                q.add((i+1)*col+j);
                visited[i+1][j]=true;
            }
       }
       distance++;
    }
}
```

But what if we can take 2 steps at a time, like "left left" or "right up". Then how to calculate the distance from every INF to its nearest gate (0)? Can we still use BFS?

Comment: Why not? In your code, you seem to test top, right, left, bottom. What does prevent you to also test diagonals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can. Right now you are testing the coordinates:

```
(i+1, j)
(i,   j+1)
(i-1, j)
(i,   j-1)
```

Which correspond to the values immediately to the north, south, east, and west of `(i, j)`. Just add the tests for:

```
(i+1, j+1)
(i-1, j-1)
(i+1, j-1)
(i-1, j+1)
```

Which correspond to the diagonals around `(i, j)`.

**Edit:** I misread the original post. You'll also need to add any other possible combinations, like `(i+2, j)`, which corresponds to "right right". It will be helpful to make a graph of possible results and make a full list before starting.

Just be careful. The code you have is a pretty messy, and it's easy to make a mistake while adding the four statements. Go slowly and triple check your work.